# How to convert MP4 video to MPEG format including AAC audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, aac, mpeg

I am trying to convert MP4 video to MPEG video that includes AAC audio.

```
ffmpeg -i Kung.Fu.Panda.mp4 -y -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f mpeg -movflags +faststart -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -crf 22 41ad2d08-f3d6-4ac4-a81b-854538025543.mpeg
```

It occurs the following error.

```
Unsupported audio codec. Must be one of mp1, mp2, mp3, 16-bit pcm_dvd, pcm_s16be, ac3 or dts.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Is there an option to convert to MPEG that includes AAC audio?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [MPEG TS Standards](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000335.shtml) are pretty clear on which audio codecs you can use. You can use "aac_mp2" but not "aac_mp4" (the latter is what ffmpeg's `aac` codec refers to). Even if you can brute-force FFmpeg to mux AAC stream on MPEG, no player can read such file. Why is this important to you?

Comment: MPEG-TS accepts both MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 AAC. The OP is outputting to MPEG-PS and our muxer does not accept AAC for that.